# Elasticsearch define wildcard mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I define mapping to series of indexes in Elasticsearch?

Elasticsearch indexes usually split by date/time and it is tedious to define mapping to each date/time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [Index Templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) for **indexes**.

I think you can use **regex** to match your index name, and automatically create index mapping by **template**, like:

```
PUT _template/template_1
{
  "template": "\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d", //index name match
```

Comment: Official docs says nothing about regex but having wildcard is enough for my purpose. Thanks for support!